# divide lengthy sms and read together

Tags: android

I am working on an Android sms application.

I have a problem with sending SMSs. If the message length is exceeds 160 then I have to send those sms as two, ie chars 0-159 in the first sms and the remaining in the second.

When the SMS reaches the Inbox it must be merged back into a single message.

Is there any way to do this?

Please help me friends.

Comment: Have you looked at multipart (concatenated) SMS? See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concatenated_SMS

Comment: @DavidWasser...i read..But in android prospective any help?..

Comment: On Android you can send multipart SMS using http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html#sendMultipartTextMessage(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.util.ArrayList%3Cjava.lang.String%3E,%20java.util.ArrayList%3Candroid.app.PendingIntent%3E,%20java.util.ArrayList%3Candroid.app.PendingIntent%3E) and when you receive a message you get the whole thing (the parts are concatenated by the SMS system on the phone automatically)

Comment: See also http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html#divideMessage%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: @DavidWasser..You mean sendMultipartTextMessage() ..right?Then the multipart message will reach in inbox as one .????

Comment: yes, if you sendMultipartTextMessage() then the multipart message arrives in the INBOX as a single message.

Comment: oke..thank you..Can you please post it as an answer.Then I could accept.

Comment: @DavidWasser..Can you please post it as an answer.Then I could accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at multipart (concatenated) SMS? See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concatenated_SMS

On Android you can send multipart SMS using `SmsManager.sendMultipartTextMessage()` and when you receive a message you get the whole thing in the INBOX (the parts are concatenated by the SMS system on the phone automatically).

See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html